# salesrule_validator_process run twice

Tags: event-observer

i have wrote a observer based on event salesrule_validator_process

```
<events>
    <salesrule_validator_process>
        <observers>
            <test_test>
                <type>model</type>
                    <class>test_test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>test</method>
            </test_test>
        </observers>
    </salesrule_validator_process>
</events>
```

the function

```
public function test($observer) {
    ......

    $connection->insert('test_test', $__fields);

    .....
}
```

the function has ran twice, inserted two records to DB, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: what actions did you take?

Comment: apply a coupon code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal to see the event executed twice.
The cart data is recalculated every time you display the cart.
So you got your first call to the observer in the action that applies the coupon code, then the cart page is reloaded and you see the second call made when the cart data is re-validated and recalculated.
To make your observer run only when you apply the coupon code you can check for the action being performed.

You can add this in your observer:

```
$action = strtolower(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName());
if ($action == 'checkout_cart_couponpost') { //if on the apply coupon action
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: So , how can i make my observer only insert once?

Comment: see my updated answer.